# how to extract text from a div block or hyperlink in BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

imagine I have a webpage

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://www.example.com/something'

result = requests.get(url).content
#print(result)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result,"lxml")
result = soup.find_all("div", class_="header-subtitle")
print(result)
```

the result will be like

```
[<div class="header-subtitle"><a href="https://example/cat1" title="cat1">Cat1</a> <span>/</span> <a href="https://www.example.com/cat2" title="cat2">Cat2</a> <span>/</span> <a href="https://www.example.com/cat3" title="cat3">Cat3</a>
</div>]
```

where I need to extract `Cat1` , `Cat2` and `Cat3` , it could be one level only , or keep going to Cat4 , Cat5, Cat6 ...etc

I tried

```
for div in result:
    print(div.find('a').contents)
```

but it only gives me the `Cat1` ,  the rest 2 are missing

also tried with regex to extract, but couldn't make out the regex properly to fit it

Comment: Instead of doing `div.find('a').contents`, do `for a in div.find_all('a'): print(a.contents)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get your goal as mentioned by MattDMo or alternativly take a look at [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
[a.get_text(strip=True) for a in soup.select('div.header-subtitle a')]
```

To get the text of an element you could use [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<div class="header-subtitle"><a href="https://example/cat1" title="cat1">Cat1</a> <span>/</span> <a href="https://www.example.com/cat2" title="cat2">Cat2</a> <span>/</span> <a href="https://www.example.com/cat3" title="cat3">Cat3</a>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[a.get_text(strip=True) for a in soup.select('div.header-subtitle a')]
```

##### Output

```
['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3']
```